# JQuery, High Charts, not finding function?

Tags: jquery, function, highcharts

I'm currently using High Charts on my website. I have everything setup so it works perfectly on jsfiddle, jquery is loaded via ajax, the highcharts script is also loadedfine.

Here is the jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jy8BA/1/

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

However when i go to run that code on my own website it fails and comes up with the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highcharts'
```

I would expect this to be due to the highcharts script not loading correctly, however using the developer tools with chrome I discovered that highchart and jquery loaded perfectly fine in a short period of time. Ive tried almost everything including using .setTimeout to pause the jquery from running in case that allowed highcharts more time to load?

Here is a link to the website im making in case you want to use the developer tools and have a look for yourself: (Please note that i have just found out that occasionally it works however if you refresh the page or change pages it doesnt work again?)

http://nclearningsurvey.info/

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Furthermore ive just discovered that if i clear all browsing history including the cache and any cookies it works fine again then stops if i refresh the page.

Comment: you have two versions of jQuery on your page. Fix this and try again.

Comment: From what i can tell i only have 1? http://imgur.com/P2HWYFz

Comment: Take a look at your `<head>` section. You have `<script charset="utf-8" async="" src="//img3.wsimg.com/wst/v7/WSB7_J_20131114_0846_RATT_558/libs/jquery/jq.js">` and `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">`, both of those are jQuery.

Comment: I have removed the second ajax version from google from the code, and its still returning the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably because `highcharts.js` is loaded when jQuery is not yet available.

Highcharts plugin requires jQuery to work correctly. You have to place `highcharts.js` **after** `jquery.js`.

Now you have `<script charset="utf-8" async="" src="//img3.wsimg.com/wst/v7/WSB7_J_20131114_0846_RATT_558/libs/jquery/jq.js">` (with `async` attribute), which means the rest of page is parsed while jQuery is being loaded.
Sometimes it'll load before `highcharts.js` (and everything will work) and sometimes not... and you'll get errors.

Remove `async` and you should get rid of those errors:

```
<script charset="utf-8" src="//img3.wsimg.com/wst/v7/WSB7_J_20131114_0846_RATT_558/libs/jquery/jq.js">
```